# Rails eventmachine not initialized evma_install_oneshot_timer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, faye

I'm using `Rails 4.1.1`, `Thin 1.6.2`, `Redis 2.8.9` (with `Hiredis` driver), and `faye-rails` gem.

I use `faye-rails` to subscribe to changes on a few models,
and I use `Redis` for other (unrelated) stuff.

When I tried to call `create` on a `faye-observed` model (let's say Apple), it throws an error like this:

```
2.1.1 :001 > Apple.create
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `apples` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-06-01 17:26:54', '2014-06-01 17:26:54')
   (7.6ms)  ROLLBACK
RuntimeError: eventmachine not initialized: evma_install_oneshot_timer
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:323:in `add_oneshot_timer'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:323:in `add_timer'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/timers.rb:12:in `initialize'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/deferrable.rb:173:in `new'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/deferrable.rb:173:in `timeout'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-1.0.1/lib/faye/protocol/envelope.rb:11:in `initialize'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-1.0.1/lib/faye/protocol/client.rb:357:in `new'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-1.0.1/lib/faye/protocol/client.rb:357:in `transport_send'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-1.0.1/lib/faye/protocol/client.rb:346:in `block in send'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-1.0.1/lib/faye/protocol/extensible.rb:23:in `call'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-1.0.1/lib/faye/protocol/extensible.rb:23:in `pipe_through_extensions'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-1.0.1/lib/faye/protocol/client.rb:343:in `send'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-1.0.1/lib/faye/protocol/client.rb:92:in `handshake'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-1.0.1/lib/faye/protocol/client.rb:131:in `connect'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-1.0.1/lib/faye/protocol/client.rb:270:in `publish'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/faye-rails-2.0.0/lib/faye-rails/controller.rb:45:in `publish'
... 27 levels...
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in `create'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Notice the `RuntimeError: eventmachine not initialized: evma_install_oneshot_timer`.

The error alternates between that, and `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)`.

After some time digging, the error only occurs when I'm trying to **save** an observed Model.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Do your controller extends `FayeRails::Controller`? Is your `FayeRails::Middleware` in use?

Comment: Hi. Can you check in console ```EM.reactor_running?```

Answer (score 2):

I use this code with Faye

```
$faye = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost/faye')
class Wrapper
    def self.publish(text)
       run_event_machine
        $faye.publish("/base", text)
    end

    def self.run_event_machine
        Thread.new { EM.run } unless EM.reactor_running?
        Thread.pass until EM.reactor_running?
    end
end
```

and when needs to send data just:

```
Wrapper.publush("the truth is out there")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call Faye (and EventMachine) from rails console. 
Rails console doesn't run EventMachine, only webserver does. If you need it working you should use: `Faye.ensure_reactor_running!` in rails console or rake tasks.